# Time Machine space

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a iMac with a hard drive of 1TB. Used 536 GB. It has an external hard drive of 1TB with Time Machine and the normal copies. The computer had a problem that did not afected the hard drive and has been 2 months to repair.

Now the iMac works well and I connect the external hard drive of 1TB for the Time Machine back up and it says that there is no space. It says "it needs 528 GB"

I do not undestand. Does it mean that it does not recognize the copy made 2 months ago? if I have 536GB used, isn't 1TB in the external drive enough ?

Comment: Time Machine may think it's a 'new' machine - open it, open backups.backupdb & see if it has 'myMac' & 'myMac(2)' listed.

Comment: @Tetsujin. No, It has not created myMac(2)

Answer (score 3):

http://pondini.org has massive amounts of info on troubleshooting Time Machine. In particular, ["Reconnecting"  to  your  backups](http://pondini.org/TM/B6.html) may answer your question.

Comment: It seems that the only solution is to buy a new external hard drive and make a new copy from now. (as I do not want to delete the old copies) if I have 536GB used, do I need a 1TB hard drive or 2TB is necessary ?

Comment: The steps on ["Reconnecting" to your backups](http://pondini.org/TM/B6.html) did not help you?

Comment: I do not want to try the terminal. It is too risky for me. The rest of things does not work

Comment: I understand your aversion to the Termimal, but sometimes it's the only way. Just be sure the source is reputable if you don't understand the commands—or take the time to learn enough UNIX to understand them :)